# AWS IAM Authentication page Customization

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-iam, identity-management

Can we customize AWS IAM Authentication page with our own logo.

AWS COGNITO AND API GATEWAY

### Edit 29 Jan, 2023

In simple words, I need to customize Default login page of AWS for IAM users. I attached the pic above.. Is that possible? I tried API gateway and AWS Cognito for this. But, I can't catch that.

This is the default AWS Authentication Page we want to customize:

[image: efault AWS Authentication Page]

Comment: Of course you [can](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-app-ui-customization.html).

Comment: I try to login into AWS with our own branded logo and customised page, instead of AWS logo and official login page. Is that possible?

Comment: Ok, but you have to help us help you by posting more information about your use case. Show us what have you tried so far and/or what your configuration looks lo far so that we can replicate your use case and show what can be done to achieve your goal.

Comment: In simple words, I need to customize Default login page of AWS for IAM users. I attached the pic above.. Is that possible? I tried API gateway and AWS Cognito for this. But, I can't catch that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your edit. It appears that you want to customize the AWS Management Console login page, not the AWS Cognito login page.

If so, the answer is **no, you can't customize the AWS Management Console sign-in webpage by removing or obscuring the AWS logo**. This is the account a customer uses to interact with AWS services. Changing a logo in your AWS Management Console could give the false impression that another company is providing AWS cloud services. Review AWS legal documents that are applicable to your case (customers located in different parts of the world may be subject to different regulations). It is common for cloud service providers to include a standard clause in their terms and conditions that specifically prohibits removal of the AWS trademark:

> You will not remove, modify, or obscure any copyright, patent, trademark or other proprietary or attribution notices on or in any software.

You can check available customization options to your AWS Management Console [here](https://aws.amazon.com/console/features/).

> You can configure settings like the default Region you want to load after sign in, your preferred language, and how favorite services display in the favorites bar.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response and detailed information..

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can

1. Sign in to the Amazon Cognito console. If prompted, enter your AWS credentials.
2. In the navigation pane, choose Manage User Pools, and choose the user pool you want to edit.
3. Choose the UI customization tab.

full docs
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-app-ui-customization.html

Comment: I need to login into AWS with IAM user credentials, but login page should be customized with own branded logo and own customized page, instead of official AWS page.

Comment: for the iam log in page you need to go to the IAM Identity Center console, under Dashboard, go to the AWS access portal section at the bottom of the page.
Choose Customize.
it is limited as to what you can do

Comment: You shared the method for customizing URL. I already did that. But, my actual need is to customize the aws logo, with our own branded logo for IAM users.